# Are we on the brink of 'Armageddon'?

Tags: eschatology

My question is addressed to those who accept that Jesus Christ will return at a time of extreme crisis : and that his return will (immediately) signal the end of time ; the end of this present creation ; the general resurrection of all the dead ; the judgment of every soul of man ; and the beginning of an Age that shall never end, under new heavens and upon a new earth.

This time of extreme crisis is named, symbolically, in the Revelation of Jesus Christ, as 'Armageddon'; the use of this word (in Christian circles)  denoting that event of extreme crisis which heralds the end of time.

[To be clear, I am not seeking an answer from those who expect a repeat of Jewish sacrifices and a 'reign of Christ on (this, present) earth'.]

---

Yes, we have been through extremities before : two world wars, and, particularly, the crisis when Kennedy and Khrushchev conflicted over missiles in Cuba (which occurred at the time of my eleventh birthday).

But now we have a man who has said, publicly, 'Why do I need a world, without Russia in it' and ' if you [interfere] you will face consequences greater than any you have faced in history'.

The man in question is reported to [wear a crucifix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Putin#Religion) around his neck given to him by his mother. It would appear that he represents himself as having authority from God in regards to the rule of this present world.

These quotes are taken from a [BBC correspondent's article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-60551140), written today in Moscow, who warns that *this one man* has (humanly speaking) the power, the ability and the apparent motivation, to do as he threatens.

---

Are we on the brink of Armageddon ?

---

*Edit after Comment*

I have deliberately not referenced anything political. I am not interested in earthly politics. I am interested in the *spiritual concept* which may (or may not) be presently manifested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of the last book in the Bible, the Revelation of Jesus Christ, is that it was given by God "to show unto his servants things which must shortly come to pass" (1:1) Therein, God's battle to finally judge all wickedness is named as "Armageddon" (16:16). It is spoken of elsewhere with various details given, which link in with previous biblical prophecies. But if these two points are not taken into account at the start of trying to answer such a question as this, everyone will just keep going round the houses, lost, due to not employing the spiritual 'compass' this last book of the Bible provides.

**First Point:**  This final prophecy was given by Christ after his ascension back to heaven, so ***the things "which must shortly come to pass" apply to that time forward, only to end at his spectacular and unexpected return to earth***, to usher in the Day of Judgment and Resurrection. This means we have been living in "the last days" for near-on 2,000 years. And, in every century, in every generation of Christians, they have seen the prophecy working out. The horsemen of the Apocalypse have been riding forth, throughout the earth, from Christ's ascension, and they won't stop until God reigns them in. Various plagues from heaven have been poured out by God on to this earth, and as the wicked increase in hatred and persecution of God's people, so those plagues intensify. They will build up to a crescendo that culminates in Armageddon. This means that every generation of Christians can live through whatever happens on earth in their life-time, prepared for and expecting that culmination. The visions given have been written down for the edification of the saints. They are to fortify their faith so that they will stand solid on the Rock, Christ, in every century. This means that whether or not Armageddon starts in my life-time (and I've already had my "three-score-and-ten" years) my faith is unshaken in God sovereignly working his purposes out, including in current events.

**Second Point:** Armageddon is not a man-made war. ***It is God's war***, his final war against all wickedness. The Revelation shows that politicians are just puppets, whose strings are being pulled by demonic forces trying to get them all lined up for the battle of Armageddon. Chapter 26 shows that men do not repent, nor give God the glory. Then John writes:

> "And I saw three unclean spirits like frogs come out of the mouth of
> the dragon, and out of the mouth of the beast, and out of the mouth of
> the false prophet. For they are the spirits of devils, working signs
> which go forth unto the kings of the earth and of the whole world, to
> gather them to the battle of that great day of God Almighty... called
> in Hebrew Armageddon" (vss. 13-14 & 16).

War-mongers like Genghis Khan, Vlad the Impaler, Hitler, Stalin and Putin do their evil worst, but they don't realise that they are puppets in the hands of unseen demonic powers, trying to trigger God's war of Armageddon. But God is in control! God's timing is exquisitely perfect, and he determines when Armageddon starts. We do not have to concern ourselves for even a minute as to when Armageddon will begin. ***Our only concern is to be living in light of the First Point!***

Only if we **grasp the Revelation to be vital preparation for us to live in faith so that, whenever "the last trump" sounds and Christ returns without warning, we will not be terrified**, seeking the mountains to fall on us to hide us from the wrath of the Lamb, will we benefit from that Revelation.

By the time God's people on earth are safely gathered in to "the barn" immediately prior to angels gathering the vine of the earth, to trample all its 'grapes' in the wine-press of God's wrath, it will be too late for vain speculation. Those who do not belong to Christ by faith will be trodden.

Revelation chapter 14 verses 12 to 20 deals with the one harvest, which has two 'reapings'. Once the first reaping starts (those "that keep the commandments of God, and the faith of Jesus") it will be too late for everybody else. Armageddon will catch them unawares, and totally unprepared. For **instantly "the good wheat" is "bundled" into "the barn", then begins the vine of the earth being cut and cast into the great winepress of the wrath of God**.

If anybody wants to check out this view of Armageddon, they could go to the link below, to find out about the book I gathered this from. It has just been reprinted and can be obtained from the address given on the web-page. It is called *"The Revelation of Jesus Christ"* by John Metcalfe. It takes over 600 pages to expound this last book of the Bible. http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

***Conclusion: The answer to the question is*** that, because we could be on the brink of Armageddon starting, Christians need to live every day in light of all that God has given to prepare his people for that event. After all, you or I might die before Armageddon starts, and it is the spiritual state people are in at the point of stepping out of time and entering eternity that matters. **The book of the Revelation has been given to us so that every generation of Christians will be prepared for every and any eventuality; it has not been given so that we might second-guess the timing of God as to when, exactly, Armageddon 'should' start. It is to show us how we are to live as faithful people in a faithless world - it is to fortify our faith irrespective of when Armageddon might start.**

Answer (score 4):

**Are we on the brink of “[Armageddon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armageddon)”?**

Possibly, but only time will tell.

First of all, what is Armageddon?

> [Armageddon](https://www.britannica.com/place/Armageddon), (probably Hebrew: “Hill of Megiddo”), in the New Testament, place where the kings of the earth under demonic leadership will wage war on the forces of God at the end of history. Armageddon is mentioned in the Bible only once, in the Revelation to John, or the Apocalypse of St. John (16:16).
>
> The Palestinian city of Megiddo, located on a pass commanding a road connecting Egypt and Syria, was probably chosen as a symbol for such a battle, because it had been the scene of many military encounters owing to its strategic location. (Megiddo was also the site of a crucial battle in 1918 during the First World War and lent its name to the victor: Lord Allenby of Megiddo.) The term Armageddon has often been used by Protestant fundamentalists to refer to an impending cataclysmic struggle between the forces of good and evil. (See apocalyptic literature.) It has also been used figuratively, often by peace activists, to describe a possible nuclear world war.

Is [Vladimir Putin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Putin) possibly the Antichrist?

Maybe. Again time will tell. At least one person thinks his actions are diabolical and that person is Pope Francis.

> Vatican City — Pope Francis has denounced the “diabolical and perverse logic” of launching a war in Ukraine in his strongest public comments yet.
>
> Francis also called Sunday for humanitarian corridors to welcome Ukrainian refugees fleeing the “tragic” invasion of their homeland.
>
> Francis has refrained from calling out Russia by name as he seeks to mend ties with the Russian Orthodox Church, and he again omitted any reference to Moscow on Sunday. But he said: “Those who make war forget humanity,” adding that warfare “relies on the diabolical and perverse logic of weapons, which is the farthest thing from God’s will.”
>
> Francis repeated his call for the faithful to mark Ash Wednesday this week as a day of fasting and prayer to show solidarity with the “suffering people of Ukraine.” - [Live updates: Belarus may join Ukraine invasion, U.S. official says](https://www.ctvnews.ca/world/live-updates-belarus-may-join-ukraine-invasion-u-s-official-says-1.5797953)

At least one politician thinks Putin is a genius for taking steps to acquire the Ukraine. Is Trump the false prophet mentioned in the Apocalypse? Maybe and then maybe not.

> Donald Trump has said that Vladimir Putin is “very savvy” and made a “genius” move by declaring two regions of eastern Ukraine as independent states and moving Russian armed forces to them.
>
> Trump said he saw the escalation of the Ukrainian crisis on TV “and I said: ‘This is genius.’ Putin declares a big portion of the Ukraine … Putin declares it as independent. Oh, that’s wonderful.”
>
> The former US president said that the Russian president had made a “smart move” by sending “the strongest peace force I’ve ever seen” to the area. - [Trump praises ‘genius’ Putin for moving troops to eastern Ukraine](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2022/feb/23/trump-putin-genius-russia-ukraine-crisis)

Are we on the brink of Armageddon? Every generation believes it is to one degree or another. In any case, we show always be prepared for we know not the hour Our Lord will return.

> The Beast (Greek: Θηρίον, Thērion) may refer to one of two beasts described in the Book of Revelation.
>
> The first beast comes "out of the sea" and is given authority and power by the dragon. This first beast is initially mentioned in Revelation 11:7 as coming out of the abyss. His appearance is described in detail in Revelation 13:1–10, and some of the mystery behind his appearance is revealed in Revelation 17:7–18.
>
> The second beast comes "out of the earth" and directs all peoples of the earth to worship the first beast. The second beast is associated with Revelation 13:11–18 the false prophet.
>
> The two beasts are aligned with the dragon in opposition to God. They persecute the "saints" and those who do "not worship the image of the beast [of the sea]" and influence the kings of the earth to gather for the battle of Armageddon. The two beasts are defeated by Christ and are thrown into the lake of fire mentioned in Revelation 19:18–20.

In any case, we must be attentive to the voice of Our Lord and Sacred Scriptures. Being careful not to misinterpret the Word of God or let our imaginations run wild.

> [Signs of the End of the Age](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2024%3A3-14&version=ESV)
>
> 3 As he sat on the Mount of Olives, the disciples came to him privately, saying, “Tell us, when will these things be, and what will be the sign of your coming and of the end of the age?” 4 And Jesus answered them, “See that no one leads you astray. 5 For many will come in my name, saying, ‘I am the Christ,’ and they will lead many astray. 6 And you will hear of wars and rumors of wars. See that you are not alarmed, for this must take place, but the end is not yet. 7 For nation will rise against nation, and kingdom against kingdom, and there will be famines and earthquakes in various places. 8 All these are but the beginning of the birth pains.
>
> 9 “Then they will deliver you up to tribulation and put you to death, and you will be hated by all nations for my name's sake. 10 And then many will fall away and betray one another and hate one another. 11 And many false prophets will arise and lead many astray. 12 And because lawlessness will be increased, the love of many will grow cold. 13 But the one who endures to the end will be saved. 14 And this gospel of the kingdom will be proclaimed throughout the whole world as a testimony to all nations, and then the end will come. - Matthew 24:3-14

The only thing necessary for the triumph of evil is for good men to do nothing.” This might also apply to countries, least they do things only through diplomacy. I will not interpret this, but let others do their own personal interpretations!

[**Estote Parati**](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2024%3A44&version=NIV)

It seems that St. Hildegard of Bingen (1098- 1179 AD) thought the world was going to be hit by a comet towards the end of time.

A couple of months ago, I heard about NASA’s attempt to deflect a comet that might be on a collision course with the bright blue planet we live on. If this comet hits us, it could possibly alter the way we live on earth.

I doubt the asteroid will hit the earth, but my unwelcoming question stands. If they think it was going to miss the earth, why did they send a rocket to deflect this comet in the first place.

> NASA predicts that the massive asteroid will pass by Earth on December 11, just a month and a few days from now. The asteroid has been classified as 4660 Nereus, and NASA does consider it very hazardous. The organization says that the asteroid is almost three times the size of a football pitch — roughly the size of the Eiffel tower.
>
> While it could be hazardous if it hits the Earth, NASA says the asteroid will fly by the planet at a distance of roughly 3.9 million kilometers. That distance is ten times greater than the area between the Earth and the moon, so it shouldn’t cause any issues on our planet. In the past, scientists have considered missions to the asteroid, but have never gone through with them.
>
> Eleanor F. Helin originally discovered 4660 Nereus in 1982. Nereus is just one of several asteroids included in the Apollo group. All of the asteroids in this group are known for passing close to the Earth as it orbits the sun.
>
> The asteroid orbits the sun every 664 days. However, scientists predict that it won’t come close to the Earth again until March of 2031. After that, it’s expected to come close again in 2050, though its closest approach isn’t predicted to arrive until February of 2060, roughly forty years down the line. As is the case with next month’s pass, however, neither of those passes are expected to be close enough to pose any risk of impact. - [NASA is tracking a 1,000-foot-tall asteroid that’s headed towards Earth](https://bgr.com/science/nasa-is-tracking-a-1000-foot-tall-asteroid-thats-headed-towards-earth/)

Could the asteroid **4660 Nereus** be the biblical **Wormwood** of the Apocalypse!

> The third angel blew his trumpet, and a great star fell from heaven, blazing like a torch, and it fell on a third of the rivers and on the springs of water. The name of the star is ***Wormwood***. A third of the waters became wormwood, and many died from the water, because it was made bitter. (Rev 8:10–11)

Comment: Keep an eye on the skies, if this is the start of Armageddon, we will soon know.

Answer (score 2):

Theologically speaking, no.

The word "Armageddon" comes from Revelation 16:16, and is a transliteration of *Har Megiddon,* or "the Hill of Megiddo," where the Final Battle is to take place, as the culmination of a war in which "all the world" is set against Israel.

[Megiddo](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Megiddo,+Israel/@32.5800285,35.1755541,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x151daafce57fc2f3:0x953accbb2cdc81ca!8m2!3d32.577899!4d35.179972) is a place in Israel, well over 1000 miles away from the current conflict in Ukraine.  This conflict, furthermore, does not even come close to involving all the world, with virtually everyone other than Russia and Ukraine choosing to stay out of it, and Israel is nowhere in sight.

Therefore, whatever is currently going on there, it is definitively *not* Armageddon.

Comment: As far as I understand it, the question is not saying that Armageddon has started. It seems, rather, to be asking whether the war Putin has started in Ukraine could turn out to be "the brink" of Armageddon. Your answer seems to depend on the belief that Armageddon must be geographically located on a small, precise bit of land in Israel, but the question is not about the location of Armageddon. Just a friendly comment!

Answer (score 2):

There's a popular saying that goes, "Those who don't know history are doomed to repeat it." The corollary when dealing with prophesy in the Bible is that those who don't know history are doomed to misinterpret Biblical prophecy that has long since been already fulfilled.

Before we look at what Revelation says about Armageddon, let's look at another passage that is often closely tied to the same discussion: Matthew 24.

The chapter begins in Jerusalem as Jesus is coming out of the Temple. The disciples are impressed with the Temple buildings, recently refurbished and expanded, and point them out to Jesus. He responds:

> “You see all these, do you not? Truly I tell you, not one stone will be left here upon another; all will be thrown down.

The scene then shifts a short distance east of Jerusalem to the Mount of Olives:

> When he was sitting on the Mount of Olives, the disciples came to him privately, saying, “Tell us, when will this be, and what will be the sign of your coming and of the end of the age?” Jesus answered them, “Beware that no one leads you astray. For many will come in my name, saying, ‘I am the Messiah!’ and they will lead many astray. And you will hear of wars and rumors of wars; see that you are not
> alarmed; for this must take place, but the end is not yet. For
> nation will rise against nation, and kingdom against kingdom, and
> there will be famines and earthquakes in various places: all this
> is but the beginning of the birth pangs.

Now notice what Jesus says will happen next:

> Then they will hand you over to be tortured and will put you to death, and you will be hated by all nations because of my name. Then many will fall away, and they will betray one another and hate one another. And many false prophets will arise and lead many astray. And because of the increase of lawlessness, the love of many will grow cold. But the one who endures to the end will be saved. And this good news of the kingdom will be proclaimed throughout the world, as a testimony to all the nations; and then the end will come.

*You* in verse 9 refers to *the original disciples to whom Jesus is speaking*.

The original disciples were persecuted and most of them executed by the end of the first century CE Jesus said this would occur *after* "wars and rumors of wars, etc." were already occurring.

Let's continue reading the next paragraph (vv. 15-28):

> So when you see the desolating sacrilege standing in the holy place, as was spoken of by the prophet Daniel (let the reader understand), then those in Judea must flee to the mountains; the one on the housetop must not go down to take what is in the house; the one in the field must not turn back to get a coat. Woe to those who are pregnant and to those who are nursing infants in those days! Pray that your flight may not be in winter or on a sabbath. For at that time there will be great suffering, such as has not been from the beginning of the world until now, no, and never will be. And if those days had not been cut short, no one would be saved; but for the sake of the elect those days will be cut short. Then if anyone says to you, ‘Look! Here is the Messiah!’ or ‘There he is!’—do not believe it. For false messiahs and false prophets will appear and produce great signs and omens, to lead astray, if possible, even the elect. Take note, I have told you beforehand. So, if they say to you, ‘Look! He is in the wilderness,’ do not go out. If they say, ‘Look! He is in the inner rooms,’ do not believe it. For as the lightning comes from the east and flashes as far as the west, so will be the coming of the Son of Man. Wherever the corpse is, there the vultures will gather.

This prophecy was fulfilled in 70 CE when Legio X Fretensis [the Tenth Roman Legion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legio_X_Fretensis) sacrificed pigs along with sheep and oxen to "purify" (according to Roman beliefs) the site of the Temple as it was being destroyed by the Romans. They would have also done this [to commemorate their own dead](https://www.revelationrevolution.org/why-historians-believe-titus-sacrificed-a-pig-to-the-ensigns-in-the-temple-in-a-d-70/) who had died in the battle to take control of Jerusalem and in particular, those who had died in the fighting inside the Temple itself. Beyond that, the coat of arms the Tenth Legion was marching under during the destruction of Jerusalem was this:

[image]

The chapter continues with language that would have been familiar to the disciples from [the apocalyptic literature of the Old Testament](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/57070/48815):

> Immediately after the suffering of those days

> the sun will be darkened,
> and the moon will not give its light;
> the stars will fall from heaven,
> >    and the powers of heaven will be shaken.

> Then the sign of the Son of Man will appear in heaven, and then all the tribes of the earth will mourn, and they will see ‘the Son of Man coming on the clouds of heaven’ with power and great glory. And he will send out his angels with a loud trumpet call, and they will gather his elect from the four winds, from one end of heaven to the other.

Many interpret verses 29-31 to be about the end of time in our current generation's future. But there are several problems with that interpretation.

First, it ignores the obvious references to apocalyptic literature on the Old Testament with which the disciples would have been very familiar. All of these same symbols were used in the Old Testament to describe the destruction of Solomon's Temple by the Babylonians.

Second, it ignores the historical events that took place with the destruction of Solomon's Temple. The disciples knew that history, and would have understood that Jesus was saying that just as the first temple was destroyed by the Babylonians, the second Temple that they had just marveled at would also be destroyed.

Third, Jesus told them this destruction would happen *during their lifetimes*.

Continuing to the next paragraph:

> From the fig tree learn its lesson: as soon as its branch becomes tender and puts forth its leaves, you know that summer is near. So also, when you see all these things, you know that he is near, at the very gates. Truly I tell you, *this generation will not pass away until all these things have taken place* (italics added). Heaven and earth will pass away, but my words will not pass away.

Jesus is talking to his disciples who were with him on the Mount of Olives when he said, **"This generation will not pass away until all these things have taken place."**

Those things, in fact, happened in 70 CE with the destruction of Jerusalem and the great diaspora. Jesus is offering hope that even though his people will be physically scattered, he will continue to gather the Kingdom of God to himself, not only from among the Jews living in Jerusalem, Judea, and Galilee, but also from among the people of the surrounding nations and lands.

He then clarifies further:

> But about that day and hour no one knows, neither the angels of heaven, nor the Son, but only the Father. For as the days of Noah were, so will be the coming of the Son of Man. For as in those days before the flood they were eating and drinking, marrying and giving in marriage, until the day Noah entered the ark, and they knew nothing until the flood came and swept them all away, so too will be the coming of the Son of Man. Then two will be in the field; one will be taken and one will be left. Two women will be grinding meal together; one will be taken and one will be left. Keep awake therefore, for you do not know on what day your Lord is coming. But understand this: if the owner of the house had known in what part of the night the thief was coming, he would have stayed awake and would not have let his house be broken into. Therefore you also must be ready, for the Son of Man is coming at an unexpected hour.

Jesus' entire point about signs is clarified when he says it will be how it was in the days of Noah. He is saying these things have been happening since the very beginning and will continue to happen until the very end. They echo the warnings from the beginning of the discourse: "And you will hear of wars and rumors of wars; see that you are not alarmed; for this must take place, but the end is not yet. For nation will rise against nation, and kingdom against kingdom, and there will be famines and earthquakes in various places: all this is but the beginning of the birth pangs."

All of these things have been going on since the beginning of recorded human history. Eating and drinking. Marrying and giving in marriage. Workers in the field. Workers grinding meal. Wars and rumors of wars. Nations rising against nations, and kingdoms against kingdoms. Famines. Earthquakes.

The house is the temple. The owner of the house represents those who rejected Jesus. The Old Testament tells of how God's Spirit left the first Temple before its destruction (Ezek. 10:18-19), so that it was no longer the house of God but had become their house (echoed by Jesus in Matt. 23:38). Again, the owner was asleep and let the house be broken into.

Now let's look at Revelation 16 and the broader context of the entire Book of the Revelation of Jesus Christ.

Revelation is written in the apocalyptic literary genre. Much of the language is symbolic, just as the Old Testament apocalyptic writings were. Those who read Revelation and equate it to our contemporary events have done so because they don't know the history that was occurring right before the very eyes of the Church's first generation. Revelation is a testimony to the faithfulness of God to his people in the face of the intense persecution they were experiencing, both from the Jews and the Roman Empire. It's an assurance that the Lamb has already won the battle with death and the powers of this Earth who are powerless to stop the Kingdom of God.

The climatic event at the end of Revelation 16 is immediately preceded by the only place in the book of Revelation where the Greek word Harmagedōn (Ἁρμαγεδών) appears. [it was transliterated into English by the KJV translators as 'Armageddon' because they missed one little breath mark in the Koine word which was a transliteration of the Hebrew place name Har Megiddo ('הר מגידו‎).]

The event in question is the destruction of the temple in Jerusalem. It's the final judgement for those who rejected Christ as the Son of God. The veil was ripped open and the Holy of Holies was abandoned by the Spirit of God as Jesus gave up his last breath on the cross. With the Spirit of God no longer dwelling there, it was only a matter of time until it would be destroyed.

Babylon is the Roman Empire. We then see the judgement and destruction of Rome in the following chapters. Then we see the city of New Jerusalem, the spiritual Kingdom of God with the Church as the Bride of Christ, come to fruition.

Comment: Would you say this is preterism?

Comment: This has happened already?  "And he will send out his angels with a loud trumpet call, and they will gather his elect from the four winds, from one end of heaven to the other."

Comment: @MikeBorden The trumpets blew and the walls of Jericho fell. The trumpets blew (in the apocalyptic writings of the OT) and the walls of Jerusalem and Solomon's Temple fell in the sixth century BCE.  The trumpets blew in Jesus' discourse using apocalyptic imagery and the walls of Jerusalem and the Temple fell in 70 CE.

Comment: @Mike Borden The diaspora which effected the spread of the Gospel beyond Judea and Galilee to the known world can be seen as the harvesting (gathering) of the elect. "The harvest is plentiful, but the laborers are few; therefore ask the Lord of the harvest to send out laborers into his harvest."

Comment: @GerlofLeuhof I'd say it is a recognition of what the writers of Matthew and Revelation meant when they wrote, rather than what many modern readers want it to mean when they read it. Both the Gospels and the Pauline writings are explicit time after time that the Jews rejected Jesus as God incarnate when he "tabernacled" among them, just as they had rejected, time and again, their first covenant to be a light to let the entire world know YHWH as the true and living god.

Comment: So the harvest is still happening?

Answer (score 1):

It's my opinion that it's clear to me were in the "birth pangs" stage. I base this on Matthew 24:8, where Jesus is talking. "But all these things are merely the beginning of birth pangs."

What things? At Matthew 24:3 His disciples ask Him a very specific question? "Tell us, when will these things be, and what will be the sign of your coming, and of the end of the age/world?"

Verse 5, False Christ will mislead many. Verse 6, You will be hearing of wars and rumor of wars. Verse 7, For nation will rise against nation. There will be famines and earthquakes.

Verse 8, the birth pangs. Verse 9, In addition to these natural calamites, followers of Jesus will have to face people who will arrest them and hand them over to be tortured and even killed. Verse 10, Many will fall away and deliver up one another.

Verse 11, And many false prophets will mislead many. Verse 12, Lawlessness is increased, most people's love will grow cold. Verse 14. This gospel shall be preached in the whole world for a witness to all the nations, and then the end will come.

It goes without saying that all of these things are taking place. However, I have no idea when we reach the point that the gospel has been preached in all the world.

"BUT" Jesus at verse 15 gives us a clue. He says, "Therefore when you see the Abomination of Desolation which was spoken of through Daniel the prophet, STANDING IN THE HOLY PLACE, (let the reader understand.)

Now, I don't know if the "Holy Place" is the temple or maybe Jerusalem/Judea/the nation of Israel. What I do know is at Matthew 24:16 Jesus says to flee, or get out of Dodge. So, to answer your question it appears that something unwelcomed may be on the verge of happening at least according to the signs of the birth pangs.

Answer (score 1):

I recently studied the history leading up to the fall of Byzantium in 1453 and the General Crisis of the 17th century. The sequence of war, civil war (and attendant famine), pestilence and death, followed by persecution of the survivors can be found in each. These match the riding out of the four horseman of the Apocalypse and the opening fifth seal (which triggers a great persecution).

Bernard Capp's 1970 thesis on the "Fifth Monarchy Men" is an interesting read. False prophets, rapid formation of small sects, and expectations that the millennium had arrived ran rampant in 17th century England and elsewhere.

Those two epochs seemed to match Revelation, but the pattern eventually fizzled out. I believe that history is fractal, with certain patterns repeating at smaller and larger scales. The series of events spoken of in Revelation hold messages for many audiences.

1. For Christians throughout history, as a warning to persevere.
2. For people going through civilizational crisis, to guide the wise through difficult times.
3. For the people living through the final chapter of history, to advise them and encourage them that the Lord is on his way.

I believe that we are in the midst of a civilizational crisis. Thus aspects of our times will match events in Revelation. We cannot know if our crisis is the final crisis or if others will follow. That is why we cannot know if Christ is about to return or if that awaits the rise and fall of another civilization.

Our current civilizational crisis seems to hinge on these events:

1. Fall of Constantinople - first horseman was Islam, war. 14th-15th centuries.
2. General Crisis following the Reformation - second horseman, civil war within the church and all Christendom. 16th-17th centuries.
3. Capitalist transformation and industrial revolution - third horseman, which dealt which created huge wealth disparities and many famines. 18th-19th centuries.
4. Nazism & Communism - Death, through genocides, collectivization, forced social conformity to eliminate class distinctions. 20th-21st centuries.
5. Fifth Seal - hatred, factions, and a great persecution. That is what is on our doorstep.

The principle involved is the focus of the transformation:

1. Government
2. Religion
3. Economics
4. Civil Society
5. Family

The persecution will spread because of a family breakdown.

After family, the next target is personal morality and piety (as distinct from group religious activity).

Once you recognize the principles involved in the process described in Revelation, you will see how difficult it is to tell whether Armageddon is at hand. We are living through a worldwide civilizational transformation. The end result can be positive - the remaking of the world into a more just and humane place. Or it can be destructive - as with Byzantium. It is up to us whether we pass the test, or descend into ruin.